# Función con condicionales JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, condiciones, formato-condicional

Me podrían apoyar ¿en qué parte de mi función la lógica está mal?

Llevo intentando un buen rato y no logro avanzar.

El problema me pide lo siguiente:

Escribir la función asientosDisponibles(), que tome como parámetro un conjunto de asientos disponibles y el asiento que quiere ocupar la persona. La función deberá verificar si el asiento solicitado se encuentra disponible y devolverle un mensaje si está disponible o no.

```js
var asientos = [3, 15, 18, 25];
var solicitado=25;

function asientosDisponibles(asientos,solicitado) {
    for (let i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
        if (solicitado === asientos[i]){
            return `Felicitaciones, el asiento número ${solicitado} está disponible`;
        }else{
             return `Lo sentimos, el asiento número ${solicitado} está ocupado, pero aún quedan ${asientos.length - 1} asientos disponibles`;
        }
    }

    console.log(asientosDisponibles(asientos,solicitado));
}
```

Comment: Me sigue mandando el siguiente error: Errores:
La función asientosDisponibles([3, 15, 18, 25], 25) debe retornar el mensaje "Felicitaciones, el asiento número 25 está disponible"

Answer (score 5):

No necesitas un ciclo para verificar si el asiento solicitado está dentro del arreglo, es suficiente con el método [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) que devuelve verdadero si existe o falso si no.

No entiendo porqué usas `asientos.length - 1` para devolver la cantidad de asientos que aún están disponibles, sobra el `- 1`.

```js
function asientosDisponibles(asientos, solicitado) {
    if(asientos.includes(solicitado)) {
        return `Felicitaciones, el asiento número ${solicitado} está disponible`;
    }
    return `Lo sentimos, el asiento número ${solicitado} está ocupado, pero aún quedan ${asientos.length} asientos disponibles`;
}

console.log(asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 15));
console.log(asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 50));
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema principal es que estás usando el operador de asignación `=` en vez de uno de comparación `==` o `===`. Al hacer esto lo que ocurre es que a la variable `solicitado` le asignas el valor que hay en la posición `i` del arreglo y luego JavaScript intenta convertir este valor en un booleano que es lo que usa el `if`. Como el valor es diferente de `0` este se avalúa a `true` y por esto siempre te indica que el asiento está disponible.

Además no puedes poner el `return` dentro del `if` y del `else` ya que solo comprobaría la primera posición. Te recomiendo poner solo el `if` y si se evalúa a `true` retornar ahí mismo y poner el otro `return` al fuera del bucle.

Por último, para que los mensajes sean correctos deben mostrar el valor del asiento que está buscando en vez de uno fijo. Para hacer esto puede usar los *string templates*.

La solución es usar alguno de los operadores de comparación:

```
function asientosDisponibles(asientos,solicitado) {
    for (var i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
        if (solicitado === asientos[i]){
            return `Felicitaciones, el asiento número ${solicitado} está disponible`;
        }
    }
    
    return `Lo sentimos, el asiento número ${solicitado} está ocupado, pero aún quedan ${asientos.length - 1} asientos disponibles`;
}
```

Si quieres profundicar en la conversión automática de tipo en JavaScript te recomiendo comenzar por esta sección del libro [Eloquent JavaScript: Automatic Type Conversion](https://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html#h_AY+YGu6qyM).

Comment: Me sigue mandando error aunque agregue a la condición dentro de if doble "==" .

Comment: @AuraMH tienes razón, ni me había fijado en todos los detalles del código. Edité la respuesta para que aborde todos estos.

Comment: M esta saliendo un último error, y no logro descrifrarlo @E.Betanzos, mira: missing ) after argument list ¿me apoyas por favor?

Comment: @AuraMH en cuál línea??

Comment: no dice, solo me manda el mensaje "Errores:
missing ) after argument list"  , Disuclpa no estaría faltando un else?

Comment: @AuraMH si no pones todo tu código va a a ser difícil ver que pasa.

Comment: Ya actualize el post, así esta todo mi código completo

Comment: @AuraMH ahí no hay problema, agrega cómo estás llamando a la función.

Comment: Listo ya lo volvi a actualizar de nuevo :)

Comment: @AuraMH vas a tener que revisar todo tú código porque en el que compartes no está presente el error que indicas.

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando variables globales en la funcion como variables locales, eso vuelve a inicializar las variables y borran sus valores. Borra esas variables del argumento.

Comment: me sigue saliendo error :(

Answer (score 0):

```
function asientosDisponibles(asientos, solicitado) {
  for (var i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
    if (asientos.indexOf(solicitado) !=-1) {
      return ( "Felicitaciones, el asiento número " + solicitado + " está disponible");
    } else {
      return ("Lo sentimos, el asiento número " + solicitado + " está ocupado, pero aún quedan " + asientos.length + " asientos disponibles" );
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Hola Estefanía, para que la respuesta sea de mayor calidad y ayude más a la gente, es mejor si pones una explicación de por qué crees que esta es la respuesta correcta. Quizá explicar el código, o lo que haces distinto, o dónde estaba el error, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var asientos = [15, 28, 44, 45, 70];

var solicitado=25;

function asientosDisponibles(asientos,solicitado) {
   for (var i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
    if (solicitado == asientos[i]){
     return "Felicitaciones, el asiento número 25 está disponible";
    }    else {
        return "Lo sentimos, el asiento número 78 está ocupado, pero aún quedan 4 asientos disponibles";
    }
   }   
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Es importante que señales [qué hace el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)).