# Problema con el retorno de un mensaje de una funcion

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con la siguiente función, en la cual, debo tomar un parámetro como el conjunto de asientos disponibles ademas de también tomar el parámetro del asiento que quiere ocupar la persona (también se debe verificar si el asiento solicitado se encuentra disponible y devolverlo en un mensaje) pero me devuelve el siguiente error: "La función asientosDisponibles([3, 15, 18, 25], 78) debe retornar el mensaje "Lo sentimos, el asiento número 78 está ocupado, pero aún quedan 4 asientos disponibles".

```
function asientosDisponibles(asientos, solicitado) {
for (var i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
    if (solicitado === asientos[i]) {
        return ("Felicitaciones, el asiento número " + solicitado + " está disponible");
    }
}
 return ("Lo sentimos, el asiento número" + " " + solicitado + " " + "está ocupado, pero aún quedan" + " " + asientos.length - 1 + " " + "asientos disponibles");
```

}

Comment: El problema esta en la concatenación que haces, ¿por qué no usas *template strings*?

Comment: Esto ya se preguntó [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/431764/54039)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el mensaje de error, como indica el comentario de @BetaM, más específicamente en donde calculas el tamaño del array.

**" "+ asientos.length - 1 +" "** en esta parte ocurre que estas restando 1 a un string lo que retorna como resultado NaN, luego continua concatenando los siguientes strings. Ver MDN [sustracción](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction#sustracci%C3%B3n_de_no_num%C3%A9ricos)

Una posible corrección es usar paréntesis: **" "+ (asientos.length - 1) +" "**

Leyendo tu enunciado entiendo que **no** hay que restar 1 al valor que retorna asientos.length

Igualmente no entiendo por que concatenar los espacios vacíos por separado si en el primer mensaje lo haces correctamente.

Código para el mensaje de error:

```
return ("Lo sentimos, el asiento número "+ solicitado +" está ocupado, pero aún quedan "+ asientos.length +" asientos disponibles");
```