# Array con for y condiciones

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, function

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

Nos piden que escribamos la función `asientosDisponibles()`, que tome como parámetro un conjunto de asientos disponibles y el asiento que quiere ocupar la persona. Nuestra función deberá verificar si el asiento solicitado se encuentra disponible y devolverle un mensaje claro y prolijo al cliente como en los ejemplos siguientes:

**EJEMPLO 1**

Ejemplo si se encuentra el asiento disponible:

```js
asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 15);
```

El resultado debería ser:

```
"Felicitaciones, el asiento número 15 está disponible"
```

**EJEMPLO 2**

Ejemplo si no se encuentra el asiento disponible:

```js
asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 50);
```

El resultado debería ser:

```
"Lo sentimos, el asiento número 50 está ocupado, pero aún quedan 5 asientos disponibles"
```

Y mi código es el siguiente:

```js
function asientosDisponibles(asientos, solicitado) {
  for (var i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
    if (solicitado == asientos[i]) {
      return (
        "Felicitaciones, el asiento número " + solicitado + " está disponible"
      );
    } else {
      return (
        "Lo sentimos, el asiento número " +
        solicitado +
        " está ocupado, pero aún quedan " +
        asientos.length +
        " asientos disponibles"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: lee tu codigo.. ponele comentarios.. si dentro del if, los dos son return, entonces no hay for que valga, porque solo comparas una sola vez no?

Comment: Esto ya se preguntó aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/431764/54039

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Función con condicionales JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431764/funci%c3%b3n-con-condicionales-javascript)

Comment: Ya intente esa pregunta y lamentablemente tampoco me ayuda, pero gracias (:

Comment: @MiriamHernández, [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/432002/54039) funciona.

Comment: @Triby, si ya intente pero me sigue saliendo error,  ahora me aparece el siguiente: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @David, Si, lo se, el error me sale cuando pongo el código de la respuesta que me puso triby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fin lo resolví! :D

```
function asientosDisponibles(asientos, solicitado) {
  for (var i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
    if (asientos.indexOf(solicitado) !=-1) {
      return ( "Felicitaciones, el asiento número " + solicitado + " está disponible");
    } else {
      return ("Lo sentimos, el asiento número " + solicitado + " está ocupado, pero aún quedan " + asientos.length + " asientos disponibles" );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: El bucle for no es necesario, la función **indexOf( parámetro )** se ocupa de  recorrer el array hasta encontrar (o no) el valor pasado como **parámetro** . Si bien la respuesta es correcta creo que el ejercicio espera que escribas tu propio algoritmo de búsqueda.

Answer (score 0):

### Esta es la razón

Tomando como punto de partida el comentario hecho por [@gibianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi), cito:

> *Lee tu código.. ponele comentarios.. si dentro del if, los dos son return, entonces no hay for que valga, porque solo comparas una sola vez no?*

Encontré lo siguiente:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
  if (solicitado == asientos[i]) {
    return "Si encuentra el elemento, se detiene aquí";
  } else {
    return "Pero también se detiene aquí si no lo encuenta";
  }
}
```

Por lo tanto, el bucle solo iterará una vez porque cualquiera va a devolver un valor. Una forma simple de corregirla es así:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
  if (solicitado == asientos[i]) {
    return "Si lo encontró devolverá esta cadena y detendrá el bucle";
  }

  return "Mientras que esta es la cadena por defecto que devolverá si no encuentra un elemento";
}
```

Es decir, se debe sacar del bucle la palabra reservada **`return`** para evitar una sola iteración. Entonces, si aplicamos los siguientes cambios tendremos:

```js
function asientosDisponibles(asientos, solicitado) {
  for (var i = 0; i < asientos.length; i++) {
    if (solicitado == asientos[i]) {
      return (
        "Felicitaciones, el asiento número " + solicitado + " está disponible"
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    "Lo sentimos, el asiento número " +
    solicitado +
    " está ocupado, pero aún quedan " +
    asientos.length +
    " asientos disponibles"
  );
}
let A = asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 15);
let B = asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 75);
console.log(A);
console.log(B);
```

Pero existen soluciones muchos más descriptivas o elegantes:

Si se utiliza el bucle **`for`**:

```js
function asientosDisponibles(asientos, solicitado) {

  for (let asiento of asientos) {
    if (asiento === solicitado) {
      return (
        "Felicitaciones, el asiento número " + solicitado + " está disponible"
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    "Lo sentimos, el asiento número " +
    solicitado +
    " está ocupado, pero aún quedan " +
    asientos.length +
    " asientos disponibles"
  );
}
let A = asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 15);
let B = asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 75);
console.log(A);
console.log(B);
```

O la solución **propuesta por [@Triby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431764/funci%c3%b3n-con-condicionales-javascript/432002#432002)** (por cierto, es una de la más elegante), que consiste en la utilización del método **`includes`** que su función, dicho de forma corta, es devolver un `true` o `false` como consecuencia de haber encontrado o no el elemento incluido en el *array* que se pretende evaluar.

Solo que en esta oportunidad se modificó un poco para utilzarse con un operador ternario.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function asientosDisponibles(asientos, solicitado) {
    const [A, B] = [
      `Felicitaciones, el asiento número ${solicitado} está disponible`,
      `Lo sentimos, el asiento número, ${solicitado} está ocupado, pero aún quedan ${asientos.length} disponibles`
    ];

    return asientos.includes( solicitado ) ? A : B;
}

// Probar la función:
let A = asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 15);
let B = asientosDisponibles([15, 28, 44, 45, 70], 75);
console.log(A);
console.log(B);
```

En esta última oportunidad, se desestructuró un *array* en elementos `A` y `B`, donde `A` representa el mensaje que se enviará al usuario si el asiento está disponible y `B` es el caso contrario.

Y luego, un operador ternario, es decir:

```js
return condicion ? verdadero : falso;
```

Que expresado en el ejemplo anterior queda así:

```js
return asientos.includes(solicitado) ? A : B;
```

> Aunque existen soluciones muchos más elegantes todavía.

Comment: Que pasa si pruebas con el asiento 28?

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que me sale el siguiente error: La función asientosDisponibles([3, 15, 18, 25], 25) debe retornar el mensaje "Felicitaciones, el asiento número 25 está disponible".

Comment: No, lo que pasa es que deberia funcionar con cuales quiera que sean los numeros, y si agrego con console.log me indica que no debo usar ese codigo, es decir, solo puedo retornar

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431764/funci%c3%b3n-con-condicionales-javascript

Comment: Ahora devuelve `"Felicitaciones, el asiento número 28 está disponible"` @alanfcm

Comment: @Usuario7, ahora con la actualización hecha devuelve `"Felicitaciones, el asiento número 25 está disponible"`, además, de presentarse varias formas de hacerla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo que le dedicaron, ya funciona (: